# Progress of a stored procedure with JPA and MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a long running **stored procedure** in **MySQL** which I call using **JPA**.

I want to periodically inform the user about the **progress** of the procedure.

**How can I achieve that?**

Here is what I've tried.
I've created a new table called *progress_table* which I update from the stored procedure.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  
  my_loop: LOOP
    -- Do some heavy work

    SET i = i + 1;
    IF i % 100 = 0 THEN
        UPDATE progress_table SET `processed` = i, `last_updated` = NOW() WHERE `id` = 1;
    END IF;
    
    IF i = 10000 THEN
      LEAVE my_loop;
    END IF;
    
  END LOOP;
END
```

I call the stored procedure this way:

```java
(new Thread(() -> {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.createNativeQuery("CALL my_proc()").executeUpdate();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
})).start();
```

It doesn't work (progress_table is not updated) because **nothing is committed** before the commit of the transaction, I guess.
When procedure finishes progress_table is updated with the correct value.

I've tried with StoredProcedureQuery but the result is the same.

Comment: Well, yeah, the idea behind transaction isolation is that changes made by a transaction are not visible for other sessions until the transaction commit. You would need to use the `READ UNCOMMITED` isolation level as I don't think there's a way to release a write lock within a transaction. As a side note, the more pertinent question I would be asking myself is why still do DB programming in 2020

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I hate DB programming. I'm not a fan of having business logic in the DB. The only reason I do it is for speed and because it will be executed only once. It executes for 33 minutes for 430k records. Maybe I'm wrong about the speed and it will be the same with JPA. Will see today, I'm gonna implement the same login in Java.